# Combined tram/train ticket from Casablanca Airport to Casa Voyageurs to Fes

Tags: trains, morocco, casablanca

Let's say we're flying into Casablanca airport and want to take the tram to Casa Voyageurs and then a train to the city of Fes. I am able to buy a ticket from the oncf-voyages website with the following (sample) itinerary. All tickets sold appear to have the same seven-minute connection time:

13:50 - Depart Gare AEROPORT Med V - TNR A22
14:23 - Arrive Gare CASA VOYAGUERS
14:30 - Depart Gare CASA VOYAGUERS - Atlas 614
18:25 - Arrive Gare FES

- What happens if our flight is delayed and we miss the tram from CMN to Casa Voyageurs?
- What happens if the tram is delayed and we miss the connection? Will we be rebooked on the following train to Fes?

Comment: It's been some years since I was there, so things may have changed in the interim, but last I knew, Moroccan trains always cost the same regardless of when you buy the ticket and (in 2nd class) can't sell out, so there was no advantage to buying the ticket in advance if you were concerned you'd miss it due to a late flight or whatever. Double-check that this is still the case before relying on it, though.

Comment: @mlc thanks, yeah, that would be our backup plan if we aren't able to find an answer. Ideally, we'd want to go in first given how similar the costs are.

Comment: What I did was buy a ticket to my destination from Casa Voyageurs (TGV in my case) online with plenty of time to spare (had to do mandatory PCR testing upon arrival at CMN earlier this year so there were long and unpredictable delays on top of the usual immigration etc.) and just bought the train ticket from the airport to Casa Voyageurs at the airport station (~40 MAD). The latter was actually a bit hard to find as some of the terminals were closed off and signage was nonexistent.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thanks for the information. Were there any (obvious) identifiable landmarks of where to go when buying the tram ticket at the airport?

Comment: At the station there are obvious ticket windows with clerks, you will have no problem. Finding the station was the hard part (had to walk outside after testing to a different terminal and pass 'passengers only' security check at the door- had to explain that I was not headed to a flight). Quite likely that's improved by now, they had just re-opened when I visited. There's a small concourse with shops to buy water snacks etc.